# how to store updated post of twitter in logstash or elastichsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, tweepy

I want to store updated post of twitter not all posts of twitter in my  **elasticsearch** index  with **logstash**  and want to have persistent connection with twitter **API** for getting data not just for once, any one know how to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'updated post of twitter'? Are you wanting to receive tweets posted by a particular user, or containing a particular hashtag?

Comment: my mean is each tweet of twitter from the time that i start my logstash  not old data of twitter just today and future tweet that's why i want to have persistent connection with twitter API